# How to start coordinate from bottom left in c?

Tags: c, graphics

Currently, if I enter coordinates 0,0 my point will show up on the top left. While that is the logical and accepted standard, I need to have it be in the bottom left(and all other coordinates adjusted appropriately) because I need to show an accurate representation of graph.

What is the best way to accomplish this in C.

Comment: What graphical library are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert one coordination system to another. In your case is is enough to subtract your `y` position the pixel from the display Y size.

```
#define CONVY(y)   (ScreenYsize - (y))
```

Comment: Is there any alternative solution for it ?